# Drawing lot object faster on OpenGL ES 1.0 on Android

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, graphic

I am working on project based on OpenGL ES 1.0, which draw lot of square and have different colors.

I did much things to optimize drawing codes, like disabling Lights or disabling DEPTH_TEST, enabling CULL_FACE and else.

But I can't find more solutions to draw one frame more faster to draw about 38000 square object.  Is there any solutions drawing lot objects faster, or interpolation library in ES 1.0? I'm stuck here for long time.

Comment: You can improve your question by showing/explaining how you are calling OpenGL ES and how you are testing (device/emulator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES 1.x is a relatively old API and has many limitations, one of which is relatively high CPU overhead. I'd highly recommend using OpenGL ES 2.0 or newer, both from a performance point of view and a future looking compatibility point of view.

If you must use OpenGL ES 1.x you really need to use vertex buffer objects. See this post for more details:

[Drawing using Vertex Buffer Objects in OpenGL ES 1.1 vs ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274219/drawing-using-vertex-buffer-objects-in-opengl-es-1-1-vs-es-2-0)

... and batch your meshes to reduce the number of unique draw calls you are making